# How to release a Log4J logger

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I'm creating a program, that will run 24/7 and will continually process multiple tasks. These tasks can run in parallel. Every task will have it's independent log file. So for every task I want to create own logger like this:

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("taskID");
```

How can I correctly release the logger so it is no longer in memory, after the task is done?

Comment: TheLostMind: the getLogger method gives me the logger object. I call it many times with different taskId, so I have many loggers. I want to release the loggers from memory when they are not needed anymore.

Comment: Do you mean that if I call Logger.getLogger("dog") and Logger.getLogger("cat") I can get the same object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to "release" a `Logger` object.  But that's OK.  If it is reachable you can still use it ... and it shouldn't be "released".  If it is unreachable, the GC will reclaim it.

By the way, if you are really talking about `log4j`, then the method you call to get hold of a named logger is [`Logger.getLogger(String)`](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Logger.html#getLogger%28java.lang.String%29).  It is defined to return an existing instance (with the same name) if one exists, so you don't need to worry about creating lots of copies of the same logger.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The problem is that I don't have many loggers with same name, but every logger has its own name. I don't want to have a memory leak in my code.

Comment: I don't think there's an solution with log4j.  It is designed on the assumption that the number of logger names is bounded, and relatively small (e.g. one per class).  If those assumptions are correct, then memory won't leak.  But if you are generating logger names on the fly, that's a bad idea: a memory leak is inevitable.

Comment: Is there an reasonable way, how to log to a separate file everytime the method is run? And more instances of the class can run in parallel.

Comment: Take a look at the MDC and NDC.  They could give you what you ultimately need.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the way a `Logger` should be instantiated. You must always make them `static` and `final`. Doing so you don't have to worry about it anymore as it's going to be only and only one instance of `Logger` per class.

Take a look at the official documentation and some manuals [online](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_quick_guide.htm). This [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/2970036908) is also very good to get started.

PS: On the other hand, I would recomend you the use of SLF4j as façade.

Comment: Yes, but I need more loggers per class, because there can be more instances of class and every instance have its own file.

Comment: Every `Logger` created is cached by `log4j` probably by using a TreeMap (I'm not sure though). I do not think you can _release_ the Loggers you create.
BTW; have you thought of overhead? Keep in mind also that you might need to declare the Logger as `transient` in case you need to log `Serializable` classes.